# How do we know what build top players use?

Tags: diablo-iii

One of the sources we can use is http://diablo.somepage.com/popular/witch-doctor#builds

However, that's not good enough. Some build, for example, it is awesome for some set items and total junk for other set items. Haunt and Locust Farm are definetly needed for  the Jade Harvester build but is not so useful on Helltooth builds.

Say I want to know who are the top players and what do they use? How do I find that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Diablo 3 Leaderboards to see who is the top for this season you can also see what builds they use. By right clicking your portrait in the game and then right clicking the person in the leaderboards and then clicking View Hero Details

Comment: +1 [Rankings](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/rankings/era/6/rift-wd) let you see everything! But How do you know if that is their farming gear or the solo rift gear ?

Comment: The Hero Details button shows the build (items/skills) used to complete that level. So even if the player changes his equipment, the one used will still be there.

Comment: As fcm said.. Sorry for not putting it in the answer.